# Delete [earthing] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retagging

The [earthing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earthing) tag only has 2 posts. I think it should either become a synonym for [grounding](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grounding), or deleted altogether.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I merged [earthing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earthing) into [grounding](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grounding) and created the synonym so that future attempts to use [earthing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earthing) will be changed.

Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks :) I didnt have enough rep on this site to suggest the synonym myself

Comment: You're welcome. With only two questions using the tag, I doubt anyone **could** have enough rep. :)